# Where to find refund data in Magento 2 database?

Tags: magento2.4

I'm trying to query refunds data from our database. The problem is I don't know where this information is located, or which column it should be. I found sales_creditmemo, some refunded columns in sales_order, some in returnmanagement_request_item, and sales_refunded_aggregated_order and sales_refunded_aggregated. However, when I compare the numbers between these tables and Reports > Sales > Refunds, and Sales > Credit Memos, all of them are different. 
So my question is, where does the data from these two reports located in the database? Where else can I find the most accurate refund statistics? Is there a way to see which element on the Magento UI located in the database?

Answer (score 0):

The following tables are used for the Credit memo. As per my understanding, i defined here,

```
sales_flat_creditmemo
sales_flat_creditmemo_item
sales_flat_creditmemo_grid
sales_flat_creditmemo_comment
```

Comment: Thanks. So you happen to know where I can find refunds in cash vs refunds by store credit as well? Are they credit_amount and credit_total_refunded inside sales_creditmemo?